# Image not being drawn in canvas when opened in new window

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I can draw image on a canvas with no problem.
But I want the image to be drawn on the canvas in a new window.
Variables have correct values, but still nothing is drawn.

Here is my code:

```
var popup = window.open();

popup.oldCanvas= oldCanvas;

popup.url = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

popup.document.open();

popup.document.write("<html><head>");

popup.document.write('<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>');

popup.document.write("<script>\n");

popup.document.write("$(document).ready(function() { \n");

popup.document.write("    function createCanvas() {                         \n");

popup.document.write("        var img = new Image;\n");

popup.document.write("        var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');\n");

popup.document.write("        var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');        \n");

popup.document.write("        newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;           \n");

 popup.document.write("        newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;         \n");

popup.document.write("        img.onload = function() {\n");

popup.document.write("              context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);                    \n");

popup.document.write("        };                                                \n");

popup.document.write("        img.src = url;                                    \n");

 popup.document.write("    };                                                   \n");

popup.document.write("    createCanvas();                                      \n");

popup.document.write("});                                                      \n");

popup.document.write("</script>");

popup.document.write("</head><body>");

popup.document.write("</body>");

popup.document.write("</html>");

popup.document.close();
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong, as the same code works fine when not drawn in new window.

Comment: What happens if you put `console.log(oldCanvas)` one line below your `$(document).ready`?

Comment: It prints the HTML canvas element: `<canvas id="mycanvas" width="100" height="100">`

Comment: In the document.write version? Can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's the plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/yZSTtAGdVVsSWmbfFJ0F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas is created but never inserted into the DOM:

```
var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);              // add to DOM
...
```